# Accurate keypoint localization in SIFT

Tags: computer-vision, feature-detection, keypoint

In his paper (Distinctive Image Feature from Scale-Invariant Keypoints), Lowe describes a way to get rid of "low contrast keypoints". This is done using a Taylor expansion up to the quadratic term:

[image: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img673/4885/4d7v81.gif]

The extremum(xhat) is found, by taking the derivative, and setting it to zero:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gwBW.gif]

By giving giving the function D, xhat as input, it is possible to determine the value of the extremum point, and by a threshold value, keep or discard the point xhat:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzyDc.gif]

Starting from the D(xhat) equation: In my understanding, the inverse is taken of a Hessian matrix (first part of the xhat equation), which in this case, is a 2x2 matrix - the second part is the first derivative, with respect to the x and y coordinates and is a 2x1 matrix: The problem is, when iterating through all the potential keypoints and taking the inverse, some of them are singular!

D(X): The value that is investigated, will have origo in D(0,0) and I'm assuming, that D is a 3x3 matrix. When D is added to the other terms, how is that to be understood - according to my calculations, when all the terms, except D, are added, one value appears - how how can this value be added to D(which is a 3x3 matrix)?

The equations can be found in the SIFT paper, page 11.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img673/4885/4d7v81.gif
This corresponds to [![enter image description here][1]][1]